# Extracting XML info using PHP

Tags: php, xml, mediawiki-templates

I have a strange formatted XML file, I want to extract the `<text xml:space="preserve" bytes="1099">` part and turn that info into its own array.

I assume I would have to find the | delimiter and split at that point, but not quite sure how to do that.

```
  <page>
    <title>Martial Ares</title>
    <ns>0</ns>
    <id>23026</id>
      <sha1>7imznp2a51dh3kslf5gtqnkpkidlvom</sha1>
    <revision>
      <id>79960</id>
      <timestamp>2014-02-25T07:24:27Z</timestamp>
      <contributor>
        <username>JScathach</username>
        <id>8024930</id>
      </contributor>
        <text xml:space="preserve" bytes="1017">{{Infobox card (2)
            |card name=[Martial] Ares
            |character name=Ares
            |release_date=May 1 2013
            |image 1=MartialAres5.jpg
            |rarity 1=Super Special Rare
            |pwr req 1=28
            |sale price 1=94200
            |max card lv 1=60
            |max mastery lv 1=40
            |quote 1=Ares prefers weapons that were used during the age of Greek myth: sword, axe, and spear.  But he can use any weapon expertly, and turn most ordinary objects into lethal weapons.
            |base atk 1=2440
            |base def 1=2650
            |max atk 1=7015
            |max def 1=7613
            |mastery bonus atk 1=915
            |mastery bonus def 1=993
            |image 2=MartialAres6.jpg
            |rarity 2=Ultimate Rare
            |sale price 2=188400
            |max mastery lv 2=200
            |quote 2=Next time I see Hercules, We're going to have a steel conversation. It's about time for him to answer for massacring my Stymphalian Birds.
            |max atk 2=9822
            |max def 2=10660
            |mastery bonus atk 2=1098
            |mastery bonus def 2=1192
            |alignment=Bruiser
            |ability=Warhawk
            |gender=Male
            |usage=Average
            |faction=Super Hero
            |effect=Significantly harden DEF of your Bruisers.
            |centretrait=None
            }}
            __NOWYSIWYG__
      </text>
    </revision>
  </page>
```

Comment: Once you have the text in "preserve", you can use PHP function array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] ) . See : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.explode.php

Comment: So the name isn't text? for example `$xml->page->preserve;` would work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the text this way:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
$text = $xml->revision->text;
```

Comment: Where does the `$string` come from?

Comment: Ok, so after seeing what you did here I found this works, `$text = $xml->page->revision->text;`

Comment: Yes that gets the text, I thought you were trying to get the space=preserve part? $string is your entire xml doc.

Comment: Oh you just wanted the contents of text? Edited. :)

Comment: `$text = $xml->page->revision->text;` gets me all the info in the `text` part now to turn that  into an array..

Comment: Yeah, sorry didn't explain very well, thanks for edit

Comment: Thanks for all your help Jessica, got an array of all the data, yay! :)

Answer (score 1):

> I assume I would have to find the | delimiter and split at that point, but not quite sure how to do that.

PHP's libxml based libraries (this includes **SimpleXMLElement** and **DOMDocument**) with their default options do preserve the whitespace within the *text* element of your question, so on that end you should run into little problems.

For the format that is encoded into the *text* elements text-value, this is *Mediawiki* syntax and at the beginning for it's largest part an [*Infobox Template*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Infobox).

```
{{Infobox
 | title = Top level title
 | data1 = {{Infobox | decat = yes | child = yes
    | title = First subsection
    | label1= Label 1.1
    | data1 = Data 1.1
   }}
 | data2 = {{Infobox | decat = yes | child = yes
  |title = Second subsection
  | label1= Label 2.1
  | data1 = Data 2.1
  }}
 | belowstyle = 
 | below = Below text
}}
```

*Example of an infobox template with embedded use*

The infobox template follows a general template syntax to name a template and provide (named or unnamed) parameters to it. You find this outlined in the [*Usage Syntax* section of *Help:Template*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Template#Usage_syntax). As Mediawiki itself is written in PHP, you can even find PHP code that is related to parsing these template codes [within it's source](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/Parser_8php.html). It shows how this data is meant to be parsed in a more strictly fahsion than the help page, however as it's source code in a little modular and structured manner, it's much more convoluted. Depending on your type of programmer, it might overwhelm you as it requires reading skills and knowledge about PCRE regular expressions.

From what I can see so far is that you need to extract (recursive) `{{` ... `}}` blocks first. Within these you parse the *title* and optionally any number of (named or unnamed) *parameters*. The delimiting character to separate these fields is `|`. I can't say if any of these delimiters can be or if how they are escaped nor can I say whether or not multi-line values are possible for fields and names - next to the examples given that show a value can be another template which then can be multiline.